# Проверка пользователя, не понимаю как изменить

Tags: python

```
import json


filename = 'numbers.json'

def get_new_username():
    """Получает новое имя пользователя"""
    username = input("What is your name? ")
    filename = 'numbers.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(username, f_obj)
    return username

def get_storage_name():
    """Получает хранимое имя пользователя, если оно существует"""
    try:
        with open(filename) as f_obj:
            username = json.load(f_obj)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return username

def greet_user():
    username = get_storage_name()
    if username:
        print("Welcome back, " + username + "!")
    else:
        username = get_new_username()
        print("We'll remember you when you come back " + username)
```

Как ее нужно изменить на тот случай, если текущий пользователь не является тем человеком, который последним использовал программу?

Comment: Формат `json` использовать обязательно или при желании можно обойтись `txt`?

Comment: обязательно раз библиотека json

Comment: Как по мне, для хранения одного имени достаточно и `txt`. В данном случае формат `json` усложняет.

Answer (score 0):

```
def itsyou():
    username = get_storage_name()
    print(username)
    a = input("its you?      <yes> or <not>: ")
    if a == "not":
        username = get_new_username()
        print("We'll remember you when you come back " + username)
        get_storage_name()
    else:
        greet_user()

itsyou()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]